# String size overflow in PHP

Tags: php

error code :
String size overflow
code :

```
     mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname);

$sql= "INSERT INTO EM (sourceindex, targetindex,source,target) VALUES ";

for($i=0;$i<$combine_arr_size;$i++){
   for($j=0;$j<$combine_arr_size;$j++){
   $sql.="('$i','$j','$combine_words_array[$i]','$combine_words_array[$j]'),";
 }
}
mysql_query(substr($sql,0,-1));
```

combine_arr_size is almost 379200,I found a solution is maximum `memory_limit`
setting , is any other choice or code changing ?

Comment: *String size overflow code* You have a string bigger than 2GB?!? What are you trying to do? I think you want to make some splits in your insert query, so that you won't go over 2GB for a string?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Insert data one by one by executing insertion code in loop, and extend maximum execution time of file.

for($i=0;$i<$combine_arr_size;$i++){
   for($j=0;$j<$combine_arr_size;$j++){
   $sql="INSERT INTO EM (sourceindex, targetindex,source,target) VALUES ('$i','$j','$combine_words_array[$i]','$combine_words_array[$j]')";
 mysql_query($sql);
}
}
```

Comment: Well maybe to run +/- half a million querys may take a while, OP could simply split it into groups of e.g. 100 sets or so

Comment: Sorry I am not getting you.

Comment: Well now an explanation why OP's method didn't worked would be nice.